# PHP Youtube downloader API Download file name videoplayback

Tags: php, json, curl, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am using Youtube download API when i click on download button video is downloading but filename showing "videoplayback.MP4"
My code:

```
<?php
$url="http://hddir.com/ajax/api.php?type=downlink&v=Is3S-6hHQLk";
$c=curl_init();
curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
$contents=curl_exec($c);
curl_close($c);
$someObject = json_decode($contents);
foreach($someObject as $obj){
$url=$obj->url;
$format=$obj->format;
echo '<a href="'.$url.'" download>video '.$format.'</a></br>';
}
?>
```

Result  [result of above code](http://new.hdbuddy.com/test.php)

Comment: What Youtube Downloader api?

Comment: api from other youtube downloader website http://128.199.104.59/content.php?cont=api

Comment: That has nothing to do with YouTube api you may want to edit your tags and remove the youtube api.

Answer (score 0):

As a quick fix, HTML5 provides a `download` attribute you may use in your anchor tag, this allows you to specify the desired file name of the download. This relies on the end user using a browser which supports this tag.

```
echo '<a href="'.$url.'" download="desiredfilename">video '.$format.'</a></br>';
```

At the time of writing browser support is:

- Chome: 14.0
- Edge: 13.0
- Firefox: 20.0
- Safari: 10.1
- Opera: 15.0

There is no requirement to specify a file extension.

More information can be found online including browser support, for example this [W3 Schools Article](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp)

**Update**: This will not work cross-origin, the file must be hosted on the same domain, as such this is not a solution for this particular problem unfortunately.

Comment: I have added still not working Please check http://new.hdbuddy.com/test.php

Comment: After a little research it appears this is not supported using cross-origin, as the file is hosted elsewhere it seems this is not the solution for you.

Comment: Ok please any help